# JAVAFX - Adding Nodes To TitledPane's Header

Tags: layout, javafx, alignment, nodes

I want to add nodes into the `TitledPane`'s header. The only way I found to do it is using `setGraphic()` method.

The problem of using that way is I cannot place them neatly. Here is what I get:
[image: Nodes Inside TitledPane's Header]

**The Codes**

```
        TitledPane tpane = new TitledPane();
        tpane.setContent(new Text("Content"));
        tpane.setExpanded(false);

        Button b = new Button("Delete");            

        BorderPane box = new BorderPane();
        box.setLeft(new Text("1 "));
        box.setCenter(new Text("Single Pane"));            
        box.setRight(b);     


        AnchorPane par = new AnchorPane(box);
        tpane.setGraphic(par);

        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.getChildren().add(tpane);
```

**The Goal**

I want to put the `Delete` button to the right, that's why I am using `Borderpane`. So the `BorderPane` need to fill the entire of the `TitledPane`'s header width minus the space for small triangle

How can it be done inside `setGraphic()` method? Or are there any better way to achieve it?

Comment: I assume you tried it without wrapping then border pane in an anchor pane. Same result?

Comment: @James_D I did and no difference happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems that support for javafx users is not as massive as the mainstream framework.

After some tries by the suggestion from @Austin, I found the way to do what I want, and this is also give dynamic sizing.

`box.prefWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty().subtract(35));`

```
    TitledPane tpane = new TitledPane();
    tpane.setContent(new Text("Content"));
    tpane.setExpanded(false);

    Button b = new Button("Delete");            

    BorderPane box = new BorderPane();
    box.setLeft(new Text("1 "));
    box.setCenter(new Text("Single Pane"));            
    box.setRight(b);     

    tpane.setGraphic(box);
    box.prefWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty().subtract(35));
    VBox vbox = new VBox();
    vbox.getChildren().add(tpane);
```

Answer (score 3):

To fix your problem try setting the width of the BorderPane to the width of the scene minus the arrow like this.

```
TitledPane tpane = new TitledPane();
    tpane.setContent(new Text("Content"));
    tpane.setExpanded(false);

    Button b = new Button("Delete");            

    BorderPane box = new BorderPane();
    box.setLeft(new Text("1 "));
    box.setCenter(new Text("Single Pane"));            
    box.setRight(b);     


    AnchorPane par = new AnchorPane(box);
    tpane.setGraphic(par);

    VBox vbox = new VBox();
    vbox.getChildren().add(tpane); 

    box.setPrefWidth(scene.getWidth()-30);//You can adjust the number to fit your needs and change scene to whatever the name of your scene is
```

I hope this helped